# Flink Streaming application writing to s3 in parquet format

Tags: amazon-s3, streaming, apache-flink, parquet

I am developing a Flink streaming application which consumes messages from kafaka/kinesis and after processing them it has to writes the output to S3 in parquet format every let say 5 minutes.

Kindly suggest an approach to achieve this as i am facing lots of issues.

Currently I am using Flink 1.4.2 as i am thinking to deploy it on AWS EMR 5.15 cluster.

Approach already tried - I have used module "flink-s3-fs-hadoop" and parquet api and flink "BucketingSink"

Comment: there is a requirement of changing the output folder in the same S3 bucket every hour as of now. For this , I am using custom implementation "org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.DateTimeBucketer"

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this? I'm running into a similar problem.

Comment: in recent version flink provided a new Sink called "StreamingFileSink" which provides support to write parquet file using s3 file system.